# How to override and reset a background-color property from a hover rule?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to reset a background-color property of a :hover rule?

I have a list of elements which are highlighted when mouse goes over. I want to apply an additional CSS rule that will disable highlighting. Here is a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/vqLuU/1/

What should I put in the second appearance of the "style1:hover" rule in order to disable highlighting at all? The result must be the same with case when all "style1:hover" rules are removed.

I do not want to redefine all styles ("green" and "blue") again. My goal is to disable the "style1:hover" rule.

HTML:

```
<div class="style1 green">AAA</div>
<div class="style1 blue">BBB</div>
```

CSS:

```
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
.style1:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

.style1:hover {
    /* How to disable highlighting from here? */

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you feel the need to declare the same rule twice? If you just want to not highlight when that `style1` class is on an element, then make the rule more specific or use the `!important` keyword for the `background-color` property.

Comment: @Jasper I cannot change or delete the first appearance of the rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: this may not be a viable solution as you have not mentioned whether you can use JavaScript.

You can remove the CSS rule by [editing the stylesheets](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript#Adding_and_Removing_Rules) with JavaScript. However it doesn't feel right to me, so I can't fully recommend this =) Maybe other SOers can comment on this method (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lebolo/G35jq/)).

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++ ) {
    var done = false;
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
    # Some browsers use rules (Chrome) others use cssRules (Firefox)
    var rules = sheet.rules || sheet.cssRules;

    for (var j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {
        var rule = rules[j];
        var selectorText = rule.selectorText;

        if (selectorText.indexOf(".style1:hover") != -1) {
            sheet.deleteRule(j);
            done = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (done) break;
}
```

Comment: OP mentioned he couldn't change the HTML, but he didn't say anything about adding code. If possible, it is a nice solution.

Comment: Thanks! It does the trick. Your example wasn't working in Firefox. But changing "rules" to "cssRules" fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/G35jq/3/

Comment: @Andrej No problem! I edited my answer to be more cross-browser compatible, just in case. Please accept the answer if it works for you =)

Comment: @lebolo Your example still has "sheet.rules.length" which will not work. In my case cssRules works across all browsers (IE, FF and Chrome), so no need to support both ways...

Answer (score 4):

Since the first appearance of the `.style1:hover` rule cannot be changed or removed, the only way to achieve that is by adding the following rules:

```
.green:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
.blue:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I feel the need to add a disclaimer: this solution is not very elegant, and I don't think of it as the *best* solution, I think it's the *only* possible solution given the requirements.

Comment: Had issues trying to determine what they wanted.  This would be the best solution. Would also recommend stating `!important` override to avoid conflict with `.style1` definition.

Comment: I was hopping that there will be another way :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
.style1:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

.style1:hover {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: Also `body .style1:hover {background-color: none;}`, just making it more specific than the old rule.

Comment: It doesn't work. Can you post a jsfiddle? And "none" is not a valid value for background-color.

Comment: "transparent" replaces the background color altogether

Comment: It should be noted that this does not work in all browsers. [IE6 only supports the `:hover` psuedo-class on anchor (`<a>`) tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc848866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The OP is using it on a `<div>` tag.

Comment: @Andrej - If it's not working, then you need to check to see if the style in inline or not.  Check this article:  http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/ . There are a lot of different factors that could cause this to not work, like element hierarchy.  Please post mark up with css styles.

Comment: @tPlummer I already posted the whole markup (except empty head and body). Did you open the jsfiddle-link I posted? You can try your solution there.

Comment: Sure it does.  http://jsfiddle.net/eqfGp/  Like I said in previous comment, post the relevant HTML and not just demo code.

Comment: @Andrej - Are you hitting `run` or `update` when you change your code in jsFiddle?  http://jsfiddle.net/vqLuU/5/  "I want to apply an additional CSS rule that will disable highlighting."  This disables the `background-color` property and sets it to default which is transparent.

Comment: @tPlummer On your example elements under cursor get white background (at least in Firefox and in Chrome). It is wrong. The background should not change at all.

Comment: @Andrej - the term "remove" implies to remove all BG color.  What you want is to have the `:hover` pseudo class emulate the current selectors bg-color property.  See Matthew's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I can think to achieve what I think you want is to add an extra class to the elements. I've chosen 'hoverEnabled'

You can simply add or remove the class hoverEnabled to an element to have a different `:hover` style attached.

**CSS**

```
.green {
    background-color: green;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
.style1.hoverEnabled:hover {
    background-color: #FFAAAA;
}

.style2.hoverEnabled:hover {
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="style1 green">AAA</div>
<div class="style1 blue">BBB</div>
<div class="style1 hoverEnabled green">AAA</div>
<div class="style2 hoverEnabled blue">BBB</div>
```

Comment: In my case I cannot change the HTML or existing CSS. I am able only to add additional CSS rules. Your solution requires to change the HTML.